# Misra warning for include guard

Tags: c++, misra

This is regarding MISRA rule 16-0-2 from MISRA C++ 2008 guidelines

```
Macros shall only be #define'd or #undef'd in the global namespace.
```

I understand this rule but my polyspace misra checking tool complains that following include guard declared at the beginning of file as Non-Compliant. I guess this can happen if this file itself is included in another namespace, but this is not the case with my header file.

What other mistakes in code may cause this issue?

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

... code etc ...

#endif
```

Note :
Example quoted in Misra guidelines is

```
#ifndef MY_HDR
#define MY_HDR     // Compliant


namespace NS
{
    #define FOO   // Non- Compliant
    #undef FOO    // Non-Compliant
}
#endif
```

Comment: That's one ... strange rule, it's not as if namespaces affect the pre-processor anyway but this makes it sound as if that is the case.

Comment: @unwind I believe that's the whole point of the rule. So that developers not aware of the absence of namespace-macro interaction cannot be assume the macro is scoped within the namespace.

Comment: Not a general solution, but a workaround for this problem if it is allowed: use [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) instead of include guards.

Comment: The premise of the rule (or the reasoning behind it) is that macros don't respect scope so, if they are to be used, put them outside all scopes.   Note that use of `#undef` is unconditionally forbidden by 16-0-3.    For the OP, try providing an MCVE (even if that needs to consist of a source file which includes your header, as well as your header) - people will at least be able to reason about the cause.

Comment: @stefaanv This does not work my case as it looks like not portable across platforms. Misra complains that I do have a include guard with #pragma once

Comment: Can you create a very simple hello-world program, which includes your header - and do you get the same rule violation error there ? If not, you need to go back to the code that does cause an error, and look at its entire context.

Comment: I'm not arguing with you that it's not a solution for you, I just don't understand the statement "Misra complains that I do have a include guard with #pragma once".  That sounds like you're using both the pragma and the include guard.  However, as you say and as shown in the link, it is supported in most platforms, not all.

Comment: @stefaanv I do not have both, when I had this error I used #pragma once, Polyspace complained that include guard is not defined. So I had to define the include guard removing #pragma once

Comment: @nos This does not happen for all files, only for few files. I am unable create a new file with same warning, as it does not happen for every file

Comment: @Sirish Which means it's likely the context of where your include files are used. Perhaps there are some oddball things being done in the header files that is included before the header file that produces the error. Perhaps the easiest way is to manually run the preprocessor on your problematic file and manually inspect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those header guards are placed outside any braces (in the global namespace), then your code is fine and your tool is broken. Send a bug report to Polyspace.

The rationale behind this rule is that pre-processor directives shouldn't be placed inside braces (inside namespace declarations or functions etc) because their scope is always global no matter where they are placed.